# Get AccessTypes from HttpRequestMessage instance

Tags: c#, .net, httprequest

I have a controller with access to `Request` object of type `HttpRequestMessage`.

In this controller I need the `AccessTypes` collection.

I know I can get it from `HttpRequestBase` object, but how do I get it from the `HttpRequestMessage`?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to get the `HttpRequestBase` and use it like this:

```
var context = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
HttpRequestBase request = context.Request; 
string[] accessTypes = request.AccessTypes;
```